# How does web3 handle new longest chains?

Tags: web3js, events, blockchain-fork

I have a Dapp which subscribes to events using web3. I'm wondering how I can detect that the longest chain has changed or rather how I can make sure the events that I've received are canonical. The could should also work correctly for hardforks and with both `getPastEvents()` and subscribing to new events.

During my research, I've found this question: [Is it possible to get duplicates of the log events on Ethereum when we have a fork of the chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68012/is-it-possible-to-get-duplicates-of-the-log-events-on-ethereum-when-we-have-a-fo). The answer suggests a `status` field. There is a `status` in the receipt but that's only a boolean. Also, there is no `status` in the results of `getPastEvents()` - what happens when the fork happens while `getPastEvents()` receives events?

I'm not sure how web3 makes sure that events are canonical in the current implementation. In tests with Geth, the event became visible in the Dapp after about 10 seconds which suggests that it just takes the latest block into account and doesn't wait for the usual 6 or 12 blocks for the chain to become canonical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to address this using web3 - one using a subscription and the other using `getPastEvents()` on a contract.

**Subscription**

The first - if you want to setup a subscription to receive events on an on-going basis, you can setup a subscription that includes `on("changed")`.

> on("changed") returns Object: Fires on each log which was removed from the blockchain. The log will have the additional property "removed: true".

If a log is removed, it means it was part of a block that was uncled.

Upon receiving an event, you can tentatively store it, but also set up a subscription to block headers. Once the appropriate number of blocks have been published, and if you have not received a "changed" event - you can accept this event and kill the block header listener.

[subscription documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.3/web3-eth-subscribe.html)

**Get Past Events**

If you will be calling the function at multiple instances / points in time, you could also use `myContract.getPastEvents(event[, options][, callback])` where you set the `fromBlock` and `toBlock` parameters in the options. For this you would set the `toBlock` to the result of  `web3.eth.getBlockNumber()` minus the number of blocks you think the chain needs to "settle".`

[getPastEvents documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.3/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents)

[getBlockNumber documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.3/web3-eth.html#getblocknumber)

Comment: So one option is to poll using `x = getLastBlock() - 10; getPastEvents(... { toBlock: x }`, correct? I'm trying to build a status variable which gives me the "last value of an event". With subscriptions, I see only calling `getPastEvents()` as above every time I get a block with `removed: true`. Also correct? I assume that web3 doesn't send me first all the `remove: true` events and then publishes the old events again (which are now "valid" once more).

Comment: For the sake of argument, assume that I store an `uint` value from the event and I need to know the last "valid" / correct / canonical value at all times.

Comment: To be honest, I don't totally follow your comments here. Something you could potentially do is set up your event subscription - upon receiving an event - tentatively store it, but also set up a subscription to block headers. Once the appropriate number of blocks have been published, and if you have not received a "changed" event - you can accept this event and kill the block header listener.

Comment: Thanks, to trigger on a "block received" event feels like a simple, stable, understandable solution. Can you add that to your answer plus see my edit, please.